# Row filtering of the image

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am writing the row filtering process of the image and got the following errors.

```
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed ((unsigned)pt.y < (unsigned)size.p[0]) in cv::Mat::at, file c:\opencv\3.4.1\build\install\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp, line 1128
```

I add padding to the image using the copyMakeBorder function include in opencv.

```
int filter_size = 7;
int h = filter_size / 2;
int top, bottom, left, right;
top = bottom = left = right = h;
Scalar value(0, 0, 0);
        copyMakeBorder(double_src, rowPaddedImage, 0, 0, left, right, BORDER_CONSTANT, value);

//Row filter
        for (int i = 0; i < rowPaddedImage.rows; i++) //For img
        {
            for (int j = h; j < rowPaddedImage.cols - h; j++) //For img
            {
                b = g = r = 0.0;
                for (int l = 0; l < f_size; l++) 
                {
                    colPaddedImage.at<Vec3d>(Point(i + h, j - h))[0] += rowPaddedImage.at<Vec3d>(Point(i, j - h + l))[0] * filter[l];
                    colPaddedImage.at<Vec3d>(Point(i + h, j - h))[1] += rowPaddedImage.at<Vec3d>(Point(i, j - h + l))[1] * filter[l];
                    colPaddedImage.at<Vec3d>(Point(i + h, j - h))[2] += rowPaddedImage.at<Vec3d>(Point(i, j - h + l))[2] * filter[l];
                }//Kernel loop end
            }
        }
```

**Expected results:**
Want to get the row filtered image, the same size as the original image.

**Actual results:**
I got the following error message while compiling.

```
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed ((unsigned)pt.y < (unsigned)size.p[0]) in cv::Mat::at, file c:\opencv\3.4.1\build\install\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp, line 1128
```

Comment: "colPaddedImage.at<Vec3d>(Point(i + h..." - what is mean i+h? When i = rowPaddedImage.rows - 1 what do you want from this code?

Comment: I have the column padded Mat => copyMakeBorder(double_src, colPaddedImage, top, bottom, 0, 0, BORDER_CONSTANT, value);
And I want to add the result to the colPaddedImage and do the column filter

Answer (score 0):

I remove the Point() and just only write colPaddedImage.at(i+h, j-h)[0] and that solved my problem.